# How to install Windows 10 after Debian

Tags: debian, windows, multi-boot, efi

I want to install Windows 10 on my laptop with Debian Jessie on it. I installed my Debian in EFI mode with graphical options. Could someone point me to a good tutorial, what I have to set, what to check, in order not to lose anything on my current installation of Debian, and at the end how to set GRUB with everything working without a problem and seamlessly with each other? I have at least 400 GB unused on my disk.

```
Dysk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, bajtów: 1000204886016, sektorów: 1953525168
Jednostki: sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 4096
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 4096 / 4096
Typ etykiety dysku: gpt

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048  195311615 195309568  93,1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2   195311616 1171873791 976562176 465,7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1171873792 1187497983  15624192   7,5G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  1187497984 1207029759  19531776   9,3G EFI System
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming sda1 as / and sda2 as /home.

Use the classic procedure.

- Back up your data. Extra step required if you do not know what you are doing.
- Reduce sda1 and/or sda2. If you want to reduce sda1, you can do it booting LinuxLive.
- Install the chosen version of the Microsoft sofware distribution, obviously in partitioned space not in use by user data or a Linux distribution. Let it do changes to the booting system.
- Boot LinuxLive, mount sda1, chroot it, run the grub updater.

There are plenty of sources for *shrinking partitions and inner file systems*, *LinuxLive*, *chroot* and *GRUB management*.

If you have plenty of time, you can install VirtualBox and do all the procedure in a sandboxed environment for you to familiarize before doing the real thing.

Comment: Do I have to shrink partition? I have unused space on disk, without any partition, more than 400GB. Would I be able to install there new Windows there? And afterall how to boot LinuxLive and how to update GRUB?

Comment: If you have *unpartitioned* space, you can put Windows there. It appears that your unpartitioned space follows your EFI System Partition (ESP), which means the ESP will reside between your Linux and Windows installations. This is legal, but it may limit your options for moving things around in the future. After installing Windows, you can use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) to restore GRUB to be the primary boot program. There's no need to use a live Linux to do this, although you could. (You'd need to use the command-line `efibootmgr` for this task.)

Comment: @RodSmith I tried with VirtualBox - installing Debian and then Windows. In EasyUEFI added new UEFI boot, linked to GRUB from Debian, then just _update-grub_ and everything looks fine :) Gonna try it in next days with my normal system.